# Conditional postinstall in package.json depending on your OS?

Tags: node.js

Here in my package.json i'm running into this issue when going between my Linux machine and Windows machine:

```
"postinstall": "node.exe node_modules/bower/bin/bower install" (for Windows)
"postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install" (for Linux)
```

I have to keep swapping these lines depending on my environment - how can I do this cross-OS so it will work in both places?

I want to do something like:

```
"postinstall": isOSWindows ? "node.exe node_modules/bower/bin/bower install" : "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is that I think you do not need switch OS to run bower from local dependencies.

After you install bower as `devDepedency` you can set for example script in `package.json`

```
"scripts":{
  "postinstall": "bower install"
}
```

And then run `npm install`, should work.

This is possible because after installing bower as local dependency in `node_modules` folder an executable version of bower script is generated in .bin folder

[image]

Or if you want to switch between OS you can use this technique.

To not have to long script command I put this into external script and use `process.platform`, something like that `script.js`

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

if (process.platform !== 'win32') {
  // run scripts for Windows
  return;
}

const commands = [
  'set NODE_ENV=e2e_tests',
  'npm run start-local-test-environment',
  'grunt build',
  'nightwatch ./test/e2e/tests --skipgroup common,helpers --env chrome'
];

const executedCommands = exec(commands.join('&&'), (error) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
 }
});
```

and then in package.json script you can have:

`"postinstall": "node ./scripts/script.js",`